# Show's email success but not receiving email godaddy

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hello the phpmailer works when I'm using it on localhost but for some reason when I used a hosting from GoDaddy it won't work anymore.

I already followed almost everything related to this but it seems like I can't find any solution:

```
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$message = "Test";
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mycpanelusername'; 
$mail->Password = 'mycpanelpassword';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 25; 
$mail->setFrom('testemail@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress($email, 'Joe User');
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');  
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');
$mail->isHTML(true);  
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = $message ;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Did you check spam or junk folder ?

Comment: SMTPSecure = 'ssl' is very unlikely to work on port 25. Post what you see with SMTPDebug = 2.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this to actually send the email, at the end:

```
$mail->send();
```

And to get more infos:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: sorry about that, i already updated the code, it doesn't show an error